# How to add type hints in PyCharm?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I often find myself having to start a debugging session in PyCharm only in order to inspect a variable and look up its class with `something.__class__` so that I can insert the type hint into the code in order to make it more readable.

Is there a way to do it automatically in PyCharm via a context action, in VSCode or maybe some other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Adding type hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#adding-type-hints) in the PyCharm?

[image]

The VSCode-Python has not supported this feature, and I have submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18942) on GitHub.

Comment: brilliant! exactly what i was looking for! i didn't seem to have figured out the shortcut, given that I use a different keymap than comes ootb; it's not always inserting the expected type but it's a great starting point

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to do it automatically in PyCharm via a context action

Well **no**! Because if you're getting a type hint of a subclass at run-time that does not mean you wouldn't want to (or should) insert the type hint of the superclass instead. (Or the type hint of an entirely different class if it's a [Union](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#union-types), or even one of the unsupported features like an [Intersection](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#unions-and-intersections-of-protocols), etc... The possible combinations are countless and even tools like [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can't check for them all statically, and much less dynamically...)

So there's no way to meaningfully automate the insertion of type hints because the IDE can't infer all the possible run time types, that's the job of programmer.

> via a context action

The context actions are limited to [Adding type hints﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#adding-type-hints) but these still require you to fill in the fields by hand. You could try and use [Inlay Hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/inlay-hints.html) but Python isn't part of the default inlay languages included in PyCharm (check the list at `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Inlay Hints`.) You could try a specific plugin to work for the Python inlay hints, for example [Python Inlay Hints](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18174-python-inlay-hints) from JetBrains plugin marketplace, but I don't think it would do exactly what you want.

Lastly, there is an option called `Collect run-time types information for code insight` see [issue PY-38900](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38900) but in my personal experience this leads to inexplicable errors and often a stale cache causing more problems than it solves (reading posts on SO a few Django users find it useful but I also don't think it does what you want).

[image]

Comment: I didn't mean to add hints automatically throughout the code (my bad to have chosen an ambiguous title), but trigger a code action that would propose something useful that could be accepted with a single key

Answer (score 2):

For **VSCode** there are some **extension** for adding type hints:

- [Python Type Hint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njqdev.vscode-python-typehint)
- [*Pylance*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) in combination with [*IntelliSense* for Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

I used IntelliSense.

Comment: does this work only for the standard library? are dedicated type libraries require for 3rd party modules?

Comment: I have never try that but i think it will work